When is a trademark/wordmark considered to be in use?
As I understand it, you may register for a trademark with the intent to use.
If I have an app that has not been launched yet, but I am actively promoting it with the tradework, would this be enough covert the trademark into use status?

canada
The Trademarks Act defines "use" to mean "any use that by section 4 is deemed to be a use in association with goods or services." Section 4 says:

4(1) A trademark is deemed to be used in association with goods if, at the time of the transfer of the property in or possession of the goods, in the normal course of trade, it is marked on the goods themselves or on the packages in which they are distributed or it is in any other manner so associated with the goods that notice of the association is then given to the person to whom the property or possession is transferred.
(2) A trademark is deemed to be used in association with services if it is used or displayed in the performance or advertising of those services.
(3) A trademark that is marked in Canada on goods or on the packages in which they are contained is, when the goods are exported from Canada, deemed to be used in Canada in association with those goods.


Sorry, I am in the USA.

Of course it is. One of the most common uses of trademarks is in advertising the product.
