Can I trademark even though I have no sales?
I am a software developer developing digital products. Can I trademark my products even though I have no sales? Let me explain: I have full fledged product and point of sale etc. What I don't have is any buyers :)
I found one answer here after posting this question: https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/do-i-actually-need-sales-to-acquire-a-trademark-re-1844130.html
welcome to hear other opinions

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/105889/when-is-a-trademark-wordmark-considered-to-be-in-use

Are you trying to sell it? Have you started advertising it?

It's great that you found the answer, but consider posting it as a proper answer, not only mentioning it on the question.

Which jurisdiction are you in? The current answers seem to assume US.

The requirement is "use in commerce".
This could be in advertising and attempts to sell a good or service. Offering to sell is sufficient if it is "bona fide" and not mere a sham offer to sell. Pre-sale activity can count if the product is available to buy, although marketing without sales isn't sufficient indefinitely.
This could be in connection with an endorsement of someone else's goods or services that are used in commerce (e.g. an endorsement from "Underwriter's Laboratories").
This could be in connection with free distribution of a good or service that is intended to generate a revenue stream in some other manner (e.g. a Linux-type business model).
But, it has to be regularly and actively used in commerce. Creating a logo and trademarked brand name isn't sufficient if it isn't actively used (and for a federal trademark in the U.S., the use has to be in interstate or international commerce).
As explained at the link:

Trademark use: What is commerce?
The trademark examining rules by the USPTO refer to Section 45 of the
Trademark Act, 15 USC 1127, which defines “commerce” as “all commerce
which may lawfully be regulated by Congress.” [see TMEP 901].
According to Section 45, “use in commerce” is defined as follows:
“The term “use in commerce” means the bona fide use of a mark in the ordinary course of trade, and not made merely to reserve a right in a
mark.  For purposes of this Act, a mark shall be deemed to be in use
in commerce– (1) on goods when— (A) it is placed in any manner on the
goods or their containers or the displays associated therewith or on
the tags or labels affixed thereto, or if the nature of the goods
makes such placement impracticable, then on documents associated with
the goods or their sale, and (B) the goods are sold or transported in
commerce, and (2) on services when it is used or displayed in the sale
or advertising of services and the services are rendered in commerce,
or the services are rendered in more than one State or in the United
States and a foreign country and the person rendering the services is
engaged in commerce in connection with the services.”
Commerce matters for trademark protection because it takes more than
mere thought to protect a mark. You have to use the mark in the manner
described above in order to gain protectable and registrable trademark
rights.
What are use requirements for goods vs. services?
For goods, use in commerce refers to the product being sold and
transported within the United States in the ordinary course of trade
with the mark preferably displayed on the product itself or on
external materials such packaging, tags and labels. In certain cases,
a brochure or online point-of-sale display may suffice as a specimen
of use for goods if certain requirements are met (e.g., means for
ordering). Advertising and marketing materials are generally
unacceptable specimens for goods.
For services, use in commerce refers to the services being rendered
within the United Sales in connection with the mark. Acceptable
specimens of use for service marks may include advertising and
marketing materials displaying the mark and referencing the services
identified in the application.
How much use is enough?
Examples of insufficient usage would include token use or minimal use
for the sole purpose of supporting a trademark application. While
there is no bright line test as to the units or dollar amount
sufficient to support bona fide use in the ordinary course of trade,
the courts have been able to find insufficient usage in cases such as
a single shipment, a single sale of a handful of units, a single
transaction within a span of years, etc.
Historically, “use in commerce” referred to the offering of products
or services that crossed state lines (interstate) as opposed to sales
solely within a state (intrastate). The interstate vs. intrastate
distinction is less significant nowadays in light of ecommerce and
that the generally accepted principle that even intrastate sales can
affect interstate commerce.
Keep in mind that services must be rendered, and not merely offered.
Sales to foreign countries may also count as use in commerce.
What about pre-sales activity?
For software products such as mobile apps, use in commerce generally
refers to the launch of the product as opposed to mere marketing. Beta
testing might be sufficient to qualify as use in commerce depending
upon the level of activity.
Crowdfunding campaigns will likely be considered pre-sales activity
that does not meet the sold or transported requirement.
What if there is no use yet?
An applicant should file an Intent-To-Use application for a mark that
has not yet been used. For borderline levels of activity, filing an
ITU application is a safer approach because it provides the applicant
with an earlier filing date (i.e., “priority”) and more time to make
sufficient use of the mark before submitting evidence of usage to the
USPTO.
If a trademark application was initially filed based on use, the
filing basis of such an application may be amended to Intent-To-Use if
the use as of the filing date was insufficient.


Yes, but …
You can’t ‘squat’ on a trade mark.
While you can register your trade mark before you have and goods or services to sell, you must start using your trade mark in the protected industry. A trade mark that is not used can be deregistered for that reason.

That's not the situation. OP has the goods to sell but nobody is buying. The question is whether offering to sell something is sufficient.

yes that is exactly my dilemma. i know how to build stuff but not how to sell.

it becomes even more complicated because i am selling digital goods. what constitutes a specimen here? with physical good, i can inscribe the trademark on the good but what do i do here? If I have an application and can show screenshots of my trademark on the installer is that a satisfactory specimen?

@morpheus The web site where you're advertising it is the "specimen".

@user71659 The explanation still applies. OP can register the trade mark and it will stand but if this state of not selling anything lasts for a long time than their trade mark can be deregistered because it looks more like squatting then an honest but unsuccessful attempt to sell.
